# Characterization of polynomial injection from Q to Q?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, polynomials

I want to know if we can find (or characterize) all the polynomials $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ that induces an injection $f : \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ by evaluation.

Some examples are $x, x^{3}$, and I would like to know how to find all of them. However, please don't hesitate to let me know any useful list of examples that narrow the possibilities of $f(x)$ or references that give ways to attack this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When investigating $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots +a_0$ with $a_n\ne0$ for injectivity on the rationals, you may scale $f$ vertically to ensure $a_n=1$, translate horizontally to ensure $a_{n-1}=0$, and translate vertically to ensure $a_0=0$.
Lastly, we can scale horizontally to ensure that $a_{n-2}$ is a square-free integer (or zero).
Thus wlog. $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots +a_1x$ with $a_{n-2}$ a square free integer or zero.

In degree $1$, we thus get $f(x)=x$, which is injective.

In degree $2$, we get $f(x)=x^2$, which is not injective.

In degree $3$, we get $f(x)=x^3+ax$. 
If $a\ge 0$, this is injective.
Otherwise note $f(x)-f(y)=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2+a)$, so $f$ is injective iff there is no $z=x-y\omega\in\mathbb Q(\omega)$ with $x\ne y$ and $N(z)=|z|^2=-a$, where $\omega=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt 3}2i$ is a primitive third root of unity. 
The condition $x\ne y$, i.e. $z\notin(1-\omega)\mathbb Z$ can be ignored because if $N(z)=-a$ then also $N(\omega z)=-a$.
Consider the prime decomposition of $-a=|a|$ in the principle ideal domain $\mathbb Z[\omega]$.
If $p\in\mathbb Z$ is an inert prime in our extension (that is $p\equiv 2\pmod 3$), then $p|-a$ implies $p|z$, hence $p^2|-a$, contradiction.
If on the other hand all prime factors $p$ are not inert (i.e. split, $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$; or ramify, $p=3$), then taking one of the primes above each $p$ and multiplying these gives us $z$ with $N(z)=|a|$. (This includes the case $a=-1$ that is trivial anyway).
Thus $f(x)=x^3+ax$ with $a$ square-free is injective iff $a\ge 0$ or $a$ is divisible by at least one prime $\in\{2,5,11,17,23,29,41,47,\ldots\}$.

In degree $4$, we get $f(x)=x^4+ax^2+bx$ with $a$ squarefree.
This is even, hence not injective, if $b=0$.
We have
$$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=(x^3+x^2y+xy^2+y^3)+a(x+y)+b=(x+y)(x^2+y^2-a)+b$$
It is again an interesting problem whether this expression can be made $=0$ or not. For example, if $6|a$, $2\not |b$ and $3\Vert b$, we note that $x+y$ or $x^2+y^2-a$ must be divisible by $3$. If the latter, then $3|x$ and $3|y$, hence $f(x)\ne f(y)$ because $9\not | b$. And if the former, then $x^2+y^2-a=2x^2-a$ is even, but $b$ is not. We conclude that $f$ is injective. This looks more like a trick than a theory, but I'm sure something nice can be done - just less easy than in the quadratic case, not to mention degrees $\ge 5$.

Comment: Thank you so much for a thoughtful investigation!

Answer (score -1):

For real polynomials, it must pass the horizontal line test. A real polynomial is monotonic iff it is always increasing or always decreasing. Thus, they are the integrals of polynomials that are non-negative or non-positive. So the question is whether a real polynomial is always monotone if its restriction to $\Bbb{Q}$ is monotone under $\Bbb{Q}$'s order.

If a real polynomial intersects a horizontal line at least twice, there is a local minimum or maximum between two of those points, and the height of such a point together with the height of the line give an interval of values which are visited at least twice by the function.

The rationals are a dense subset of the reals, meaning every neighborhood of a real number has at least one rational. Therefore, that interval of values that are repeated contains at least one rational. Therefore if a real polynomial is not monotonic, then the rational polynomial is not monotonic. Therefore if a rational polynomial is monotonic, then the real polynomial is monotonic.

Clearly every monotonic real polynomial is monotonic as a rational polynomial. Therefore a polynomial is monotonic over the rationals iff it is monotonic over the reals iff it passes the horizontal line test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. If $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is injective, then $f : \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is injective, so you have found a characterization for a smaller family of the polynomial.

Comment: I think it is not immediately clear that $f$ must be monotonic. For example $x^3-2x$ is not monotonic and yet the horizontal line at $y=0$ has only one intersection with th egraph (the other two *would* be at $\pm\sqrt 2$)

Comment: So the question can be narrowed to list these non-monotonic polynomials that induces an injection $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Note, the horizontal line test for real polynomials. What's shown by the test doesn't depend on the rationality of the points of intersection - the test shows that there's a real interval over which the function is revisiting values it visits elsewhere. If one of the values taken within that interval is rational, it will fail to be monotonic. So the interval's image would have to be smaller than any rational approximation to the interval.

Comment: @LokiClock Your characterization is correct over $\mathbb{R}$. Can you show that why it is correct over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @GilYoungCheong I was only trying to separate an obvious family of injectives for the rationals from the exotic ones, like you say, but in responding to HagenvonEitzen I think I found a full characterization.

Comment: @LokiClock Do you want to imply that $x\mapsto x^3-2x$, viewed as map $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$ is *not* injective? (It is clearly not monotonic). If I'm not mistaken, $(2)$ is inert in $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^2+X+1)$, therefore $x^2+xy+y^2=2$ has no rational solutions, therefore $f(x)-f(y)=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2-2)$ with $x,y\in\mathbb Q$ only if $x=y$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : $(x+c)^3-2(x+c)=c^3+3c^2x+3cx^2+x^3-2x-2c=c^3-c+(3c^2-2)x+3cx^2+x^3.$

$c^3-2c+(3c^2-2)x+3cx^2+x^3=x^3-2x \iff c^3-2c+3c^2x+3cx^2=0.$ The rational $x$ with rational offsets $c$ from a repeated value are exactly the rational points of this ellipse. So, I guess there are no rational points, looking at the quadratic equation.

Comment: So I think the flaw in my reasoning thusfar is that there's no guarantee the repeated rationals will be repeated at rational inputs.